# Redirect subdomain on CloudFlare to Google Calendar

Tags: dns, redirect, cloudflare

I want to redirect a subdomain of a domain I have on CloudFlare, to a Google Calendar (HTML/embed version).

I assumed I needed to use Page Rules to do this, which I have done by following [CloudFlare’s documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-do-url-forwarding-with-CloudFlare-). However just following these instructions did not work for me. Apparently I need to add the subdomain to my DNS records on CloudFlare, but I don’t know how to set this up correctly since I have no server or IP to point it to (or I’m just confused as to why I need to even point it to something when I just want to forward a URL).

As mentioned I have no server to point it to – and thus can’t use a .htaccess solution – so don’t know what record type I should be using to use to just have the redirect working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So CloudFlare does support this through PageRules, you just need to get the URL correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success just using google.com as the CNAME record, then using a Page Rule to redirect everything on that domain. Because CloudFlare changes the DNS entry to its servers anyway (when you do the orange cloud thing) nobody will know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could do that directly from cloudflare, but you can solve this using your hosting.

1. Point subdomain to your hosting server `sub IN A 1.2.3.4` via cloudflare
2. Create `sub.domain.com` on you hosting
3. Place redirection script in index file in subdomain `sub.domain.com` document root:

`<?php 
 header( "Location: http://docs.google.com/your-url-and-so-on" ) ;
 ?>`

Comment: I don’t have a server I can do this on. I mention this twice…

Answer (score 0):

"subdomain to my DNS records on CloudFlare, but I don’t know how to set this up correctly since I have no server or IP to point it to"

This doesn't make much sense. A subdomain has to point to a record of some sort (A record or CNAME), so the subdomain wouldn't resolve without a record type of some sort. In order for a PageRule to work, two things have to happen:

1. The record has to be in your DNS settings.
2. The record has to have our proxy running over it.

It might be easier to figure out with the actual subdomain in question & what you're trying to forward to specifically.